# How to force selenium to have same default wait time as Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber

I'm running some tests that depend on data reloading into the page. These run fine in Capybara which pauses on `has_content` and retries if it can't find it. However they're failing in Selenium which attacks the problem immediately and doesn't do any retries.

```
Scenario: submit a question to the panel from its homepage
  When I submit the question "what's the best grease to use on my trucks?"
  Then I should be on the "Ruderiders" panel homepage
  And I should see the question entitled "what's the best grease to use on my trucks?" at the top of the feed
```

- works in Capybara
- fails in Selenium (@javascript

How can I force Selenium to do the same wait and retry that Capybara does?

Comment: Tried bumping up Capybara.default_wait_time to 10 or even 20?

Comment: I thought of that but it's not an issue with capybara. If I don't run the test with a @javascript tag it runs fine. The problem is when Selenium takes over it doesn't pay any attention to the default_wait_time

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but Selenium is just a driver that Capybara uses, if you tell Capybara to do so (by using a profile, like @javascript). So... tried bumping it a little? I wouldn't be so persistent If I haven't encountered a problem like you have right now by myself, which bumping wait time to 5 seconds solved it ;)

Comment: Thank you for this and apologies for the delay in marking the question. I haven't had a chance to fully investigate doing the bump yet as I've been bogged down in gem issues but will come back to it when I can

Comment: Ok - bumping up the default wait time seems to work - thankyou - if you want to put it into an answer I'm happy to mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your `Capybara.default_wait_time` setting and increase the default wait time if needed.

I am glad it worked for you :)